# Visual Studio Team Server CI run .NET Core xUnit test Faile

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, xunit

i have been read [xUnit getting test results in vsts](https://xunit.github.io/docs/getting-test-results-in-vsts)

after build , it's run my test , and show all testcase pass.

but the task is failed, i can't find any reason from the log.

```
vstest.console.exe 
"D:\a\1\s\Services\AuthManagement\XXXX.Management.Api.Test\bin\Release\netcoreapp2.1\XXXX.Management.Api.Test.dll"
"D:\a\1\s\Services\AuthManagement\XXXX.Management.Api.Test\obj\Release\netcoreapp2.1\XXXX.Management.Api.Test.dll"
/EnableCodeCoverage
/logger:"trx"
/TestAdapterPath:"D:\a\1\s"
/InIsolation
```

i run this command in my local nb, there's no any error.

in vsts there's had the error message

```
System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Unable to find tests for D:\a\1\s\Services\AuthManagement\XXXX.Management.Api.Test\obj\Release\netcoreapp2.1\XXXX.Management.Api.Test.dll. Make sure test project has a nuget reference of package "Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" and framework version settings are appropriate. Rerun with /diag option to diagnose further.
```

the XXXX.Management.Api.Test Project , already install Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk nuget package

Comment: And what happens when you run with /diag?

Comment: For debugging please insert a nuget restore task before the build and see if this task succeeds.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the error message, it looks up the files in obj/release folder, which should be exclude, so you can add `!**\obj\**` to exclude the files in obj folder. For example;

```
**\*xUnitTest*.dll
!**\obj\**
```